# Op-amp based over-current protection circuit not operating as expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, over-voltage-protection

I am trying to make an over-current protection circuit using an LM358 opamp and an N-type Mosfet. I have only done it on Proteus simulation, not in real life.

The problem I am having is that the voltage at the inverting input of the comparator is following the voltage at the non-inverting input of comparator (reference voltage.)

I am trying to make the [circuit as described in this link.](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/overcurrent-protection-circuit-using-op-amp)   The circuit  from that site is attached in the second picture, probably they have used the erong symbol for the IRF540N.

What should I do?

[image: CIRCUIT IN WEBSITE , IAM TRYING TO MAKE]

[image: My proteus simulation]

Comment: Don't shout in the title please.

Comment: Agreed. Please don't shout in the title. It will get you attention but not the type you want. You don't have a comparator.

Comment: Ok sorry for that

Comment: @Transistor , What do u mean that I don't have a comparator

Comment: OK. Reading the linked article it is using an op-amp as a comparator. It's OK as you've written it. Don't forget to fix the title.

Comment: The schematic symbol in the first picture looks wrong. It shows a P-channel mosfet instead of an N-channel.

Comment: The text of the article specifies an IRF540, which is an n-type MOSFET, so the schematic is using the wrong symbol. Are you sure you are using the MOSFET in Proteus with the proper orientation? Source should connect to the shunt resistor. If you have it backward the body diode of the FET will always be forward-biased, allowing voltage to develop on the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. The circuit relies on Schmitt trigger operation to lock out on over-current.*

When an over-current condition is detected the output will switch low to turn off Q1. R4 is intended to pull the reference voltage low to give some hysteresis to the circuit.

You have the sensitivity pot set at 2% of 1k = 20 Ω in your simulation. The 100k pull down will hardly affect such a low resistance so, in effect, the non-inverting input is held at a constant 0.14 V. Due to the negative feedback your circuit is just working as an adjustable constant current sink.

Note that the original circuit has VR1 = 50 kΩ. You have used 1 kΩ in your simulation. The 100k positive feedback can't beat the 1k pot.

Change the pot in your simulation and start off with it at mid-point and see if it works. Then move it back to 2% and see if it still works. If not, why not?

Tip: Turn off the grid before taking screengrabs.

Comment: [Kindly Click here to view the simulation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s1Wb832W7wmx5ijAnuxU2NeNMq-C-pON/view)

This happened when I set the POT to 50 K and then dropped the value below the sensed voltage at inverting terminal. @transistor

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to see other than the lamp is flashing. Does your simulator have an oscilloscope function?

Comment: I think the problem is that when ouput goes low , the mosfet turns off, and subsequently the voltage at inverting terminal gets low than the reference voltage and the output of comparator goes high, and  mosfet turns on again , and the cycle repeats. and it goes into loop turning off and on the lamp

Comment: I would agree. I think the latching operation of the circuit is suspect.

Comment: Any solution for this latching operation

Comment: Not with that circuit. Do you actually need it to switch off and stay off? Is current limiting with auto-reset adequate for your needs? What's the real problem you are trying to solve with this circuit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104202/discussion-between-zohaib-shafique-and-transistor).